# Network teaming VS bonding configuration

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, ethernet, bonding

as I am understanding 
we can set on Linux configuration BONDING or network teaming

both approach support LAN fail over

for example

if on the server we have the following up link

```
eth1
eth2
```

in BOND when **eth1** is fail the **eth2** will take action

the same is on network teaming

so what should be the decision between - network teaming VS bonding configuration

Comment: https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2014/06/23/team-driver/

Comment: can you described it more simply ( by answer )

Comment: I knew that RH blog post, have not delved into the theme yet. At work...

Comment: so you welcome to give the post

Comment: so what you say about ?